# LaTeX3 choice keys that set other choice keys

Tags: latex3, package-writing, l3keys

I'm trying to set up choice keys that can implicitly set other choice keys. In both the "parent" and "dependent" keys, the set of choices have the same values.

The code below does more-or-less what I want; if I pass the option `reset-question = section`, then the counter for the question environment will be reset each time a new section is started. However, if I give the question a prefix (with `question-prefix = section`), it should always reset the key at that level, regardless of the value of the `reset-question` key (i.e. overriding that key, if it is defined).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{l3keys2e}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\newcounter{question}
\keys_define:nn { teachingtools } {
    reset-question .default:n = section,
    reset-question .choices:nn = {
        part, chapter, section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph, subparagraph
    }
    {
        \counterwithin*{question}{ \tl_to_str:N \l_keys_choice_tl }
    },
    reset-question / none .code:n = {
        \counterwithout*{question}{section}
    },
}

\tl_new:N \l_@@_question_prefix_tl
\keys_define:nn { teachingtools } {
    question-prefix .choice:, 
    question-prefix / part .code:n = {
        \tl_set:Nn \l_@@_question_prefix_tl { \arabic{part} }
        \keys_set:nn { teachingtools } { reset-question = part }
    },
    question-prefix / chapter .code:n = {
        \tl_set:Nn \l_@@_question_prefix_tl { \arabic{chapter} }
        \keys_set:nn { teachingtools } { reset-question = chapter }
    },
    question-prefix / section .code:n = {
        \tl_set:Nn \l_@@_question_prefix_tl { \arabic{section} }
        \keys_set:nn { teachingtools } { reset-question = section }
    },
    question-prefix / subsection .code:n = {
        \tl_set:Nn \l_@@_question_prefix_tl { \arabic{subsection} }
        \keys_set:nn { teachingtools } { reset-question = subsection }
    },
    question-prefix / subsubsection .code:n = {
        \tl_set:Nn \l_@@_question_prefix_tl { \arabic{subsubsection} }
        \keys_set:nn { teachingtools } { reset-question = subsubsection }
    },
    question-prefix / paragraph .code:n = {
        \tl_set:Nn \l_@@_question_prefix_tl { \arabic{paragraph} }
        \keys_set:nn { teachingtools } { reset-question = paragraph }
    },
    question-prefix / subparagraph .code:n = {
        \tl_set:Nn \l_@@_question_prefix_tl { \arabic{subparagraph} }
        \keys_set:nn { teachingtools } { reset-question = subparagraph }
    },
    question-prefix / none .code:n = {
        \tl_gclear:N \l_@@_question_prefix_tl 
    },
    question-prefix .default:n = none,
    question-prefix .initial:n = none,
}
\tl_put_right:Nn \l_@@_question_title_tl { \l_@@_question_prefix_tl }

\NewDocumentCommand \ttsetup { m } {
    \keys_set:nn { teachingtools } {#1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\ttsetup{
  % reset-all = false,
  % reset-question = subsection,
    question-prefix = section
}


\end{document}
```

Attempting to simplify the defintion of `question-prefix` along the lines of the
next code sample never works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{l3keys2e}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\newcounter{question}
\keys_define:nn { teachingtools } {
    reset-question .default:n = section,
    reset-question .choices:nn = {
        part, chapter, section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph, subparagraph
    }
    {
        \counterwithin*{question}{ \tl_to_str:N \l_keys_choice_tl }
    },
    reset-question / none .code:n = {
        \counterwithout*{question}{section}
    },
}

\tl_new:N \l_@@_question_prefix_tl
\keys_define:nn { teachingtools } {
    question-prefix .choices:nn = { 
        part, chapter, section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph, subparagraph
    }
    {
        \tl_set:Nn \l_@@_question_prefix_tl { \arabic{ \tl_to_str:N \l_keys_choice_tl } }
        \keys_set:nn { teachingtools } { reset-question = \tl_to_str:N \l_keys_choice_tl }
    },
    question-prefix / none .code:n = {
        \tl_gclear:N \l_@@_question_prefix_tl 
    },
    question-prefix .default:n = none,
    question-prefix .initial:n = none,
}
\tl_put_right:Nn \l_@@_question_title_tl { \l_@@_question_prefix_tl }

\NewDocumentCommand \ttsetup { m } {
    \keys_set:nn { teachingtools } {#1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\ttsetup{
  % reset-all = false,
  % reset-question = subsection,
    question-prefix = section
}


\end{document}
```

Instead, I get the following error message:

```
|'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
| The key 'teachingtools/reset-question' only accepts predefined values, and
| 'section' is not one of these.
|...............................................
```

This doesn't make sense, as `section` is a valid choice for `reset-section`, so
something is not being passed in the right format.  I've tried various things in
the `question-prefix .choices:nn` code block, including converting the choice
value to a string, getting its integer value, and passing the token list
directly.  I haven't tried assigning the `reset-question` and `question-prefix`
keys to groups yet.

Why doesn't this work? Is it possible to clean up or optimise the code in the first
part?

Comment: The second block produces that error if you replace the `question-prefix` key definition in the first block with its contents.

Comment: Not unless I add all the other stuff to make a proper MWE. The problem is you're converting the thing to a string and then expecting it to behave normally. Don't do that and it will probably work. However, I can't test without usable code, so implementation is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Have you tried removing those string conversions? Did that work out?

Comment: Btw: `\keys_set:nx { teachingtools } { reset-question = \l_keys_choice_tl }` seems to help (remember to generate the variant). But without a proper testable MWE it's hard to say whether this really solves your problems.

Comment: @TeXnician this works exactly as desired. Does the first MWE I provided in the question not work?

Comment: @Robbie As I thought the second thing is what you are trying to achieve, I focused on that. If the expansion solved your problem, I could write up an answer if you want.

Comment: Robbie does the comment of @TeXnician solved your problem?